# How to create a temperory table with out knowing the number of column and column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a result using sql pivotand now i want this to be copied to temperory table. How can i create temp table on the fly and insert the data.i have added the output of my dynamic query

```
select
testresultid,customername
, MAX([val1])  AS [val1],MAX([11]) AS [val2],MAX([11]) AS [val2],MAX([11])
```

Comment: First of all you have to find out if you're using MySQL, MS SQL Server or SQLite... Different products...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to create a temporary table you just have to add an `into #tempTableName` before the `from statement` example:

```
select
testresultid,customername
, MAX([Compliant Information Disclosure1])  AS [Compliant Information DisclosurePostEvent],MAX([11]) AS [Compliant Information DisclosureFileValidationOverall],MAX([11]) AS [Compliant Information DisclosureCombinedOverallOutcome],MAX([11]) AS [Compliant Information DisclosureHasOutcome],MAX([Heading1])  AS [HeadingPostEvent],MAX([11]) AS [HeadingFileValidationOverall],MAX([11]) AS [HeadingCombinedOverallOutcome],MAX([01]) AS [HeadingHasOutcome],MAX([Internal Process Compliance1])  AS [Internal Process CompliancePostEvent],MAX([11]) AS [Internal Process ComplianceFileValidationOverall],MAX([11]) AS [Internal Process ComplianceCombinedOverallOutcome],MAX([11]) AS [Internal Process ComplianceHasOutcome],MAX([Meets Customer Needs1])  AS [Meets Customer NeedsPostEvent],MAX([01]) AS [Meets Customer NeedsFileValidationOverall],MAX([01]) AS [Meets Customer NeedsCombinedOverallOutcome],MAX([11]) AS [Meets Customer NeedsHasOutcome],MAX([Regulatory Compliance1])  AS [Regulatory CompliancePostEvent],MAX([01]) AS [Regulatory ComplianceFileValidationOverall],MAX([01]) AS [Regulatory ComplianceCombinedOverallOutcome],MAX([11]) AS [Regulatory ComplianceHasOutcome]

INTO #myTemp -- INSERT IT HERE

FROM (
SELECT
p.testresultid, p.customername,
```

Comment: You are welcome, if this solved your problem you may mark it as an `accepted answer` , if you can have questions, you can leave them in the comments here

Comment: Left side of the `0` (where my answer starts), there is an up and a down arrow and some checkmark. The checkmark is the `accepted answer` button. Welcome to stack overflow

Comment: Placed my dynamic sql with data getting inserted into temp table in a stored procedure and the end i am returing data from temperory table at the end of procedure. When i execute the procedure i am getting error Invalid object.

Comment: @Cheppy If you use dynamic sql, the trick is this. Inside the of the dynamic sql variable you can use temp tables, but it won't work once you take them outside of the variable. You have to use a physical. Example: `@sql = 'select * into #temp1 from table1 select * into #temp2 from #temp1 '` now If i do `select * from #temp2` outside of the @sql it won't work. After you are done with your calculations/joins inside of the @sql then export to a physical table: in the example:   `@sql = 'select * into #temp1 from table1 select * into #temp2 from #temp1 select * into myTable from #temp2'` will work

Comment: then you will have the data outside of the @sql from `myTable`. I hope I explained it in a clear way

Comment: SET @query = 'here i am inserting data to #temp table.' ..later i need this table inside the procedure to join with another table ans so on.  In this case how can i get data in temp table to join within with other tables with in the procedure

Comment: you can do it inside of the `@query`. Example: `@query = select * into #tempTable from table1 inner join table 2 on table1.id = table2.id` then inside of the same `@query` you can use #tempTable but not outside. If you want to use it outside of the `@query` at the end of the dynamic thing you have to export it in a real table. That's the way it works

Comment: and if you ask how you can join a temp with another temp. The answer is in the same way you are doing it with a normal temp. Just add the correct name ( `#temp`)

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use below query ?

```
SELECT * INTO NEW_TABLE_NAME FROM (Your entire query here) as data
```

It will create table from your data

Comment: that's not a `#temp`  you are `selecting into`

Comment: Well..I have tried this .But it resulted in to error The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: yes because order by clause have no meaning while inserting data in to another table. You can remove order by and add it when selecting from new table. Also as CM2K writes this will not be temp but physical table